# What type should a Model be to add to an Entity?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am new to Entity Framework and not that proficient in C# or MVC3, but I'm working on it.

I was able to follow [this tutorial](http://mikesdotnetting.com/Article/105/ASP.NET-MVC-Partial-Views-and-Strongly-Typed-Custom-ViewModels) and modify it to my specific needs, which has worked pretty well for listing items.

Now I am trying to use this same principle to add a new row to my Entity. However, I'm not quite sure how to go about it. Really, the only part I don't understand is what type the class should be.

```
public ???? CreateNewCollection(long id, Collection collection) {
        var newCollection = new UserCollection {
            uid = id,
            CollectionName = collection.Name,
            Type = db.CollectionTypes.Where(t => t.CollectionTypeName == collection.Type).First().ctypeid,
            CreateDate = DateTime.Now
        };

        db.UserCollections.AddObject(newCollection);
        db.SaveChanges();

        return ???;
  }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a method, and since you are performing an action and you don't look like you wish to return anything you can just mark ???? as   `void`  and remove the return statement.

This needs to be within a class of course, and to allow you to call the method without instantiating a class you could mark the method as static.

Therefore :

```
    public static class MyCollectionRepo
    {
    public static void CreateNewCollection(long id, Collection collection) {
            var newCollection = new UserCollection {
                uid = id,
                CollectionName = collection.Name,
                Type = db.CollectionTypes.Where(t => t.CollectionTypeName == collection.Type).First().ctypeid,
                CreateDate = DateTime.Now
            };

            db.UserCollections.AddObject(newCollection);
            db.SaveChanges();
    }


  }
```